# Pivot general purpose table

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have a data structure that generate a table view like this:

| seq_num | code | val | field1 | field2 | field3... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | author | King | Tokyo | London | ... |
| 0 | book | Shining | Tokyo | London | ... |
| 1 | author | Follet | Paris | Madrid | ... |
| 1 | book | Winter | Paris | Madrid | ... |

As you see, every block is related to each other by seq_num.
The pivot key and value must be CODE and VAL. The other columns has the same values for every rows in the same seq_num and must be leaves as they are (but I don't know how many will be).

So, the result must be:

| seq_num | author | book | field1 | field2 | field3... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | King | Shining | Tokyo | London | ... |
| 1 | Follet | Winter | Paris | Madrid | ... |

The pivot fields are always CODE and VAL and the SEQ_NUMBER tells which rows has to be aggregated.

Answer (score 1):

To address your initial question, just try this :

```
SELECT string_agg(val, '') FILTER (WHERE code = 'author') AS author
     , string_agg(val, '') FILTER (WHERE code = 'book') AS book
     , field1
     , field2
     , field3
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY seq_num, field1, field2, field3
```

Now if the values of the `code` column are not known before the run time and their number may vary, then I don't see any solution with a static sql statement, but a dynamic statement embedded in a pl/pgsql function may solve the issue :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aggregate_data ()
RETURNS setof record LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
  column_list AS text ;
BEGIN
  SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT 'string_agg(val, '') FILTER (WHERE code = ' || quote_literal(code) || ') AS ' || code, ', ')
    INTO column_list
    FROM your_table ;

  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
  'SELECT num_seq, ' || column_list || 'field1, field2, field3
     FROM your_table
    GROUP BY num_seq, field1, field2, field3' ;
END ;
$$
```

`SELECT aggregate_data ()` should provide the expected result.

Comment: the values of code column are not know so I can't presume "code = 'author' etc...."

Comment: @EviSvil can you look at the last update and give a feedback ?